# Can't start pocketsphinx in Unity3d game

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, pocketsphinx, pocketsphinx-android

I am trying to integrate [PocketSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid) into my Unity3d project.

In order to do this, I have integrated the [Android demo project](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo) into the Android Studio export of the Unity3d project.

When trying to the app, I get an exception saying that the following function retured -1.

```
public static final native void Decoder_setSearch(long var0, Decoder var2, String var3);
```

This method is being called when I start listening for voice commands:

```
recognizer.startListening("hello app", 10000);
```

Why does this happen? How can I resolve it?
It works perfectly in the PocketSphinx example project.

How I've set up the Recognizer:

```
Assets assets = new Assets(MyActivity.this);
File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();

recognizer = defaultSetup()
                .setAcousticModel(new File(assetDir, "en-us-ptm"))
                .setDictionary(new File(assetDir, "cmudict-en-us.dict"))
                .setRawLogDir(assetDir)
                .setKeywordThreshold(1e-45f)
                .setBoolean("-allphone_ci", true)
                .getRecognizer();

recognizer.addListener(MyActivity.this);
recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);
```

...and more info from logcat ([complete file](http://snippi.com/raw/e8tjh6k)):

```
01-29 18:01:12.989 4237-4237/com.myName.pocketSphinxTest I/SpeechRecognizer: Start recognition "hello app"
01-29 18:01:12.989 4237-4237/com.myName.pocketSphinxTest D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-29 18:01:12.989 4237-4237/com.myName.pocketSphinxTest W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4157fd58)
01-29 18:01:12.989 4237-4237/com.myName.pocketSphinxTest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.myName.pocketSphinxTest, PID: 4237
                                                                             java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
                                                                             Unity version     : 5.2.2f1
                                                                             Device model      : Osterhout_Design_Group R7-W
                                                                             Device fingerprint: R7/apq8084/apq8084:4.4.4/KTU84P/ODG_R7_V3.1.12:user/release-keys
01-29 18:01:13.019 4237-4237/com.myName.pocketSphinxTest I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4237 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You incorrectly specified the path to assets in setSearch it seems. You can find details in logcat output

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I'm pretty sure I didn't. Please check out the additional code I appended to my question. :)

Comment: You need to provide logcat output, not just the code

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I did.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev ...and here's the complete logcat file: http://snippi.com/raw/e8tjh6k

Comment: And what is the value of KWS_SEARCH? Why do you start "hello app" search and not KWS_SEARCH?

Comment: It actually has this value, I replaced "hello app" with "KWS_SEARCH". Obviously it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: What is the value of KEYPHRASE

Comment: It's simply "listen"

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Where can I even find the method Decoder_setSearch(long var0, Decoder var2, String var3), so I can try to understand why it returns -1?

Answer (score 1):

`setSearch` is called in `startListening` with the name of the search. The name of the search is `"hello app"` in your case. If the search `"hello app"` is not added before it returns -1 and throws exception. The source is available in pocketsphinx-android sources.

The error generally means you didn't add the search with the name `"hello app"` before, from your code you say that `KWS_SEARCH` has the same value of `"hello app"`, but I think there is a typo. You need to double-check that you use the same string for the search name. I would recommend you to replace "hello app" string with `KWS_SEARCH` in `startListening` call.

Comment: Thanks, but I've found the error somewhere else. onPartialResult(Hypothesis) was called with a null parameter and I didn't check for that.